# Variables are not showing up in VSCode / Xdebug PHP

Tags: php, visual-studio-code, xdebug

I'm trying to configure xdebug with VSCode (VSCcode version 1.9.1).

php.ini

```
[Xdebug]
zend_extension = D:\php\ext\php_xdebug.dll
xdebug.remote_autostart = 1
xdebug.remote_enable = 1
xdebug.remote_host=localhost
xdebug.remote_port=9000
xdebug.remote_handler="dbgp"
xdebug.remote_log = D:\site\xlog.txt
```

My default php port is 3000. `($_SERVER['SERVER_PORT'] = 3000` 
I can actually run `phpinfo()` at `localhost:3000`
and Xdebug port is set as `xdebug.remote_port = 9000`

Xdebug log:

```
Log opened at 2017-02-17 20:50:56
I: Connecting to configured address/port: localhost:9000.
I: Connected to client. :-)
-> <init xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="http://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" fileuri="file:///D:/site/index.php" language="PHP" xdebug:language_version="7.1.0-dev" protocol_version="1.0" appid="11384" idekey="Admin"><engine version="2.5.0"><![CDATA[Xdebug]]></engine><author><![CDATA[Derick Rethans]]></author><url><![CDATA[http://xdebug.org]]></url><copyright><![CDATA[Copyright (c) 2002-2016 by Derick Rethans]]></copyright></init>

<- breakpoint_list -i 1
-> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="http://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="breakpoint_list" transaction_id="1"></response>

<- breakpoint_list -i 2
-> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="http://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="breakpoint_list" transaction_id="2"></response>

<- breakpoint_set -i 3 -t exception -x *
-> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="http://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="breakpoint_set" transaction_id="3" id="113840001"></response>

<- run -i 4
-> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="http://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="run" transaction_id="4" status="stopping" reason="ok"></response>

<- stop -i 5
-> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="http://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="stop" transaction_id="5" status="stopped" reason="ok"></response>

Log closed at 2017-02-17 20:50:56
```

launch.json:

```
{
"version": "0.2.0",
"configurations": 
[{

"name": "Listen for XDebug",
"type": "php",
"request": "launch",
"port": 9000
},

{

"name": "Launch currently open script",
"type": "php",
"request": "launch",
"program": "${file}",
"cwd": "${fileDirname}",
"port": 9000
}
]

}
```

For the following test code :

```
$var = "test\n";
print $var;
var_dump($var);
```

I get this in the debug console :

```
test D:\site\index.php:5: string(5) "test "
```

But **no variables** in the debug list..

I don't know why but the variables don't appear in VSCode.

When I try to reach `localhost:3000`... here is what I get:

```
Log opened at 2017-02-17 21:38:16
I: Connecting to configured address/port: localhost:9000.
E: Time-out connecting to client. :-(
Log closed at 2017-02-17 21:38:17
```

Comment: Did you even put a breakpoint in your code?

Answer (score 6):

I had a similar issue - same log entries you provided, same symptoms, nearly the same configuration.  XDebug failed for me suddenly one day last week and all local variables began showing as 'undefined', no pop-over inspection, etc.  Debugging the same code on another host I own which is nearly identical continued to work just fine.

After uninstalling and reinstalling XDebug and the VSCode extensions involved several times and attempting many config alterations, I eventually discovered **the problem was being caused by an expression I'd placed in my watch list**.  Once the problematic expression was removed from my watchlist (which somehow survived all the uninstall / reinstall cycles) XDebug immediately started working properly again.

Sort of lame that a watchlist expression can cause the whole XDebug stack to curl up and die, but there it is.  Thought this experience worth sharing as someone else will doubtless run into a similar problem in the future and wind up here looking for an answer.

Answer (score 1):

**Got it working (only tested with php version 7).**

1. Start by downloading the correct xdebug version here:
   https://xdebug.org/wizard.php

### follow the steps..

vscode > debug > gear icon > launch.json

```
{
"version": "0.2.0",
"configurations": [
    {
        "name": "Listen for XDebug",
        "type": "php",
        "request": "launch",
        "port": 9000
    },
    {

    "name": "Launch currently open script",
    "type": "php",
    "request": "launch",
    "program": "${file}",
    "cwd": "${fileDirname}",
    "port": 9000
    }
]
}
```

vscode > File >preferences > settings.json > WORKSPACE SETTINGS

```
    // Place your settings in this file to overwrite default and user settings.
{
      "php.validate.executablePath": "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\php\\php7\\php.exe",
      "php.validate.enable":true
}
```

**php.ini** add this to end of file (note there is no path slashes in "zend_extension")

```
[Xdebug]
zend_extension = php_xdebug-2.5.4-7.0-vc14-nts.dll
xdebug.remote_enable = 1
xdebug.remote_autostart = 1
xdebug.remote_handler=dbgp
xdebug.remote_host=localhost
xdebug.remote_port=9000
xdebug.remote_log = C:\Temp\Xdebug_log.txt
```

also watch this youtube guide:

### https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xME6uHYTcLU

**Finally, when configuration is done, here is how to get the debugger in vs code to show the variable, watch, callstack:**

1. start webserver (eg port 8080.. just not on port 9000)
2. vscode > Click; Start debuggin ( listen for Xdebug)
3. in Chrome > click RELOAD (this will trigger and start the debugging) Done.

Comment: what should be php.validate.executablePath in case of ubuntu ?

Comment: @Aamir, as far I can tell, it's just your php path, which you can get by typing `which php` in console

Answer (score 0):

Delete the watch variables firstly. This is a bug of VScode.

Answer (score -1):

You need to change the host port to 3000

**Follow this:**

vscode > debug > gear icon > launch.json

```
{
"version": "0.2.0",
"configurations": [
{
    "name": "Listen for XDebug",
    "type": "php",
    "request": "launch",
    "port": 9000
},
{

"name": "Launch currently open script",
"type": "php",
"request": "launch",
"program": "${file}",
"cwd": "${fileDirname}",
"port": 3000
}
]
}
```

This worked for me